# AWK command for *

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to retrieve the fourth column of a text using awk with a criteria on the 2nd row of a file, however I am getting a blank value as output.

Here is my Input file contents
1st line : `xxxx`
2nd line : `GS*HP*IRX*029053964*20180611*114500`

I need to look for the criteria `HP*IRX*` in the input file and print the value `20180611` ( 4th column)

Here is my script

```
filedate=$(awk -F "*" '/HP*IRX/{print $4}' $file)
  echo $filedate
```

Pls advise what I am missing.. tnx!

Comment: You may be thinking that `HP*IRX` is one column, or that `20180611` is the fourth column, but `awk` isn't going to agree on either count. Your second column is `HP`, your third is `IRX`, and you want to print out the fifth column (`$5`).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `*` is a special character in a regular expression. `/HP*IRX/` will match "H" followed by *zero or more "P"* followed by "IRX"

You want

```
awk -F'*' '$2 == "HP" && $3 == "IRX" {print $5}'
```

Or, if you really want a regex

```
awk -F'*' '/\*HP\*IRX\*/ {print $5}'
```

I put a `\*` in front so you don't match a line with `fooHP*IRX`

Comment: thank you , it works .. I have another related question..  How do i search for multiple conditions.. For ex, I my input file can contain either "*" or "|" , I am trying something like recamt=$(awk -F "*" '/BPR/{print $3}' $file) || $(awk -F "|" '/BPR/{print $3}' $file)..

Comment: The formatting of your comment is broken. Please ask a new question.

Comment: got it figure it out , using awk -F'[|*]' and it worked.. thank you !!

Comment: it probably didn't resolve .. let me post it in a separate question as it's breaking my formatting..